# How to redirect to a URL binding multi routes in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/debug')
@app.route('/debug/sample')
def debug():
    pass
```

Jinja2 code:

```
{{ url_for('app.debug') }}
```

How to control the real url that Jinja2 will redirect?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.url_for

Answer (score 2):

Give each rule a different endpoint value. The default is the name of the decorated function, so both currently have the same name and the last registered takes precedence.

```
@app.route('/debug/sample', endpoint='debug_sample')
@app.route('/debug')
def debug():
    pass
```

```
url_for('debug')  # /debug
url_for('debug_sample')  # /debug/sample
```